# How to use regex to replace all semicolons inside double quoted strings by spaces?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need to replace **all** semicolos `;` in lines of a file by a space character only when the semicolon is between double quotation marks `" "`.

For example the following line

```
'in this area the semicolon should not be replaced "however in this area it ; should be" other text "another ; text" ;....'crlf
```

should be modified to

```
'in this area the semicolon should not be replaced "however in this area it   should be" other text "another   text" ;....'crlf
```

using regular expression.

I succeeded only on replacing all text between quotation marks with nothing, i.e. to delete the double quoted text.

This is what I used in ColdFusion language:

```
<cfset newline=rereplace(line,'\"[^\"]*\"','','all')>
```

Has anyone an idea how can I use regex to replace only the semicolon character by a space when it is positioned between quotation marks?

Comment: `<cfset newline=rereplace(line,';(?!(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)',' ','all')>`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tS6oL7/1

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash Raj, it works !!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below regex..

```
<cfset newline=rereplace(line,';(?!(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)',' ','all')>
```